# Strange compilation error with gnat on fixed point declaration

Tags: ada, fixed-point, gnat

Compilation fails with the F6 declaration below :

```
type F3 is delta 2.0**(-4) range 0.0 .. ((2.0**8)-1.0)*2.0**(-4);    -- byte  16#f.f#;
for f3'size use 8;

type F4 is delta 2.0**(-8) range 0.0 .. ((2.0**16)-1.0)*2.0**(-8);   -- word 16#ff.ff#
for f4'size use 16;

type F5 is delta 2.0**(-16) range 0.0 .. ((2.0**32)-1.0)*2.0**(-16); -- dword 16#ffff.ffff#
for f5'size use 32;

type F6 is delta 2.0**(-32) range 0.0 .. ((2.0**64)-1.0)*2.0**(-32); -- ldword 16#ffff_ffff.ffff_ffff#
for f6'size use 32;
```

Same failure  both on linux64/v8.0.3 and on learn.adacore.com.

*edit* error message is  "size required (65) for type "f6" too large, maximum allowed is 64"

*edit* add 'size instructions / intended upper bound in hex

*edit* added fixed type freeze trace below

```
loval -16#0.FF#E1, hival 16#0.FF#E1, Actual_Size  9
loval 0.0, hival 16#0.FF#E1, Actual_Size  8

loval -16#0.FFFF#E2, hival 16#0.FFFF#E2, Actual_Size  17
loval 0.0, hival 16#0.FFFF#E2, Actual_Size  16

loval -16#0.FFFF_FFFF#E4, hival 16#0.FFFF_FFFF#E4, Actual_Size  33
loval 0.0, hival 16#0.FFFF_FFFF#E4, Actual_Size  32

loval -16#0.FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF#E8, hival 16#0.FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF#E8, Actual_Size  64
loval 0.0, hival 16#0.FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF#E8, Actual_Size  63
```

Comment: Probably size needed to hold a value of F6 type is 65 bits while max allowed size for numeric types is 64 bits?

Comment: Yes that's my problem. See others answers for a more ada-ist view on how the size should be computed according to the type system.

Answer (score 7):

The base problem is that your GNAT does not support fixed point types with a size more than 64 bits, as the error message states. And `F6` seems to require 65 bits. This happens because for fixed point types, the [reference manual states](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-9.html):

> The base range (see 3.5) of a fixed point type is symmetric around zero, except possibly for an extra negative value in some implementations.

This means that the *base range* of type `F6` also includes the symmetric negative numbers and thus requires a sign bit. This is why, the representation of the base range needs 65 bits instead of 64 bits as you'd expect.

Now the manual also states that

> An ordinary_fixed_point_definition also defines a constrained first subtype of the type

So `F6` is a subtype of the base type requiring 65 bits. Due to the range constraints of `F6`, it would only need 64 bits of representation. As `F6` is the first subtype, we may constrain its size with an [attribute definition clause](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-3.html#S0309):

```
for F6'Size use 64;
```

This forces the compiler to try and use only 64 bits for representation. I am unsure whether this solves your problem; it could be that you cannot circumvent the error this way since the compiler requires a representible base type.

Comment: I forgot to report the size instructions in my initial question. Now edited.

Comment: My problem is that this base type / subtype processing should also forbid the use of f3/f4/f5 on 8/16/32 bits. It is not. See my comment to @DeeDee answer.

Comment: You're certainly right:   the answer to my question is somewhat related to the representability of the base type ..

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of @flyx, you can see this by invoking GNAT with the `-gnatdg` switch. The type `Tf6B` (shown in the compiler output between brackets) is the actual underlying type for (sub)type `f6`. Type `Tf6B` is (almost) symmetric around 0, as @flyx already explained based on the Ada RM, and determined to have a size of 65 bits.

**main.adb**

```
procedure Main is

   type F6 is delta 2.0**(-32) range 0.0 .. ((2.0**64)-1.0)*2.0**(-32);
   for F6'Size use 64;

   X : F6;
   Y : F6'Base;     --  This should be possible.   

begin
   null;
end Main;
```

**output** (gnatmake)

```
$ gnatmake -gnatG main.adb 
gcc -c -gnatG main.adb
Source recreated from tree for Main (body)
------------------------------------------


procedure main is
   type f6 is delta 2#1.0#E-32 range 0.0 ..
     [18446744073709551615.0*2**(-32)];
   for f6'size use 64;
   [type Tf6B is delta 2#1.0#E-32 range
     -[9223372036854775808.0*2**(-32)] ..
     [9223372036854775807.0*2**(-32)]]
   freeze Tf6B []
   x : f6;
   y : Tf6B;
begin
   null;
end main;

main.adb:3:04: size required (65) for type "F6" too large, maximum allowed is 64
main.adb:3:09: warning: declared high bound of type "F6" is outside type range
main.adb:3:09: warning: high bound adjusted down by delta (RM 3.5.9(13))
gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: My version of gnat (debian -- 8.3.0) does not output bounds :(, I got : `[type Tf6B is ???]` . I'll see how to update gnat ...

Comment: It should be similar for  other types ... for example : `Tf3B` as the base type of `F3`should be symetric around `0` and its size should be `> 8`. That's not the case. Or else I'm missing something ...

Comment: Added gnat freeze process trace in the question. My interpretation so far is that gnat is fixing required size for the base type too soon: while the max size for Tf6B is 65 it should wait for the actual range of f6 before deciding if the needed size is out of bound.

Comment: @wondering-if I used GNAT CE 2019 to generate the output of GNATmake. GNAT FSF 8.3.0 indeed does not provide the same output. I'm not sure whether GNAT fixes the required size too soon. Although the compiler can satisfy the size clauses for the (sub)types like `f3` ... `f6`, I think that (based on the statements in the Ada RM) it just also must be able to represent the underlying (base)types (`Tf3B` ... `Tf6B`). This might also be related to [ARM 3.5 (6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-3-5.html#p6).

Comment: @wondering-if Furthermore, please note that the language also allows you to actually reference this base type at any time using the aspect `'Base` (see updated example). Hence, as the base type must be available, it must also be representable.

Comment: As it seems a "legal ada problem", I'm not sure a definitive answer can be easily found . In the meantime I combined modular/interfaces.c  types to implement my requirements ...

Comment: @wondering-if If you really want to know the details, then you might want to contact the [ARG](http://www.ada-auth.org/arg.html), but I think that the rationale for having base types was already described for Ada 83 (see e.g. section 7.4 of the [Ada 83 rationale](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-07-04.html#7.4)). The idea is that the compiler always chooses a hardware compatible (native) type from which the user-defined (sub)type is derived.

Comment: @wondering-if You could then ask why no unsigned integer could be chosen then for `F6`. I'm not sure. Maybe it's related to possible compiler complexity. In particular: if you would allow 0 to max positive unsigned range as it fits in a 64-bit register, then you would also want to support a max negative range to 0. And what about all intermediate non-symmetrical ranges that also fit into a 64-bit processor register. I think that this gets very complicated, especially when you need to perform (fixed-point) arithmetic.